# How to access kubernets service of one project from pod of another project in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am facing one scenario where I have to access one Kubernetes service of GCP PROJECT X from a pod running in another GCP Project Y.

I know we can access service from one namespace in another namespace in the same project by using

> servicename.namespacename.svc.cluster.local

how can I do if I have to do similar across different GCP projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @cperez08, but adding my 5 cents.

I think you can try [Set up clusters with Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-shared-vpc)

> With Shared VPC, you designate one project as the host project, and
> you can attach other projects, called service projects, to the host
> project. You create networks, subnets, secondary address ranges,
> firewall rules, and other network resources in the host project. Then
> you share selected subnets, including secondary ranges, with the
> service projects. Components running in a service project can use the
> Shared VPC to communicate with components running in the other service
> projects.
>
> You can use Shared VPC with both zonal and regional clusters. Clusters
> that use Shared VPC cannot use legacy networks and must have Alias IPs
> enabled.
>
> You can configure Shared VPC when you create a new cluster. Google
> Kubernetes Engine does not support converting existing clusters to the
> Shared VPC model.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well project X and Y are completely different clusters, thus, I am not sure if that's possible, take a look to this https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/07/cross-cluster-services/ maybe you can have re-architect your services by federating in case High Availability is needed.

On the other hand, you can always access to the resources through a public endpoint/domain if they are not in someway connected.